# Laravel Validation- check depend input value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

In my validation function, some fields is related to other fields input value. So how can I validate it.

For example : Here is my validation function

```
 public static function validate($data) {
    return [
        'firstname'               => 'required',
        'local_or_expat'          => 'required',
    ];
}
```

So here if the `local_or_expat` value is `expat`, then there is another field `country` which is mandatory.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `required_if` like this:

```php
return [
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'local_or_expat' => 'required|in:local,expat',
    'country' => 'required_if:local_or_expat,expat',
];
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-required-if) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can use required_if rule for this.

```
public static function validate($data) {
    return [
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'local_or_expat' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required_if:local_or_expat,==,expat'
    ];
}
```

this rule means if local_or_expat value is expat then country is required too.
you can use Rule class too.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public static function validate($data) {
    return [
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'local_or_expat' => 'required',
        'country' => Rule::requiredIf($request->local_or_expat == 'expat'),
    ];
}
```